# How do I upload a gzip object to s3?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, compression

I am creating a gzip string and uploading it as an object to s3. However when I download the same file from s3 and decompress it locally with gunzip I get this error: `gunzip: 111.gz: not in gzip format` When I look at the mime_content_type returned in the file downloaded from s3 it is set as: `application/zlib`

Here is the code I am running to generate the gzip file and push it to s3:

```
for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++) {
    $content .= $i . "\n";
}

$result = $this->s3->putObject(array(
   'Bucket' => 'my-bucket-name',
   'Key'    => '111.gz',
   'Body'   => gzcompress($content),
   'ACL' => 'authenticated-read',
   'Metadata' => [
       'ContentType' => 'text/plain',
       'ContentEncoding' => 'gzip'
   ]
));
```

The strange thing is that if I view the gzip content locally before I send it to s3 I am able to decompress it and see the original string. So I must be uploading the file incorrectly, any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobject the ContentType and ContentEncoding parameters belong on top level, and not under Metadata. So your call should look like:

```
$result = $this->s3->putObject(array(
   'Bucket' => 'my-bucket-name',
   'Key'    => '111.gz',
   'Body'   => gzencode($content),
   'ACL' => 'authenticated-read',
   'ContentType' => 'text/plain',
   'ContentEncoding' => 'gzip'
));
```

Also it's possible that by setting ContentType to text/plain your file might be truncated whenever a null-byte occurs. I would try with'application/gzip' if you still have problems unzipping the file.

Comment: Should be gzencode($content) not gzcompress($content). gzencode will add the necessary header data to make a proper gzip archive.

Comment: Plus one for gzencode() instead. Also there will be issues when providing the ContentType and ContentEncoding. It worked best for me to just remove those attributes and AWS will auto select the right type and encoding from the headers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, and the only way to make it work for our file was with a code like this (slightly changed according to your example):

```
$this->s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => 'my-bucket-name',
    'Key'    => '111.gz',
    'Body'   => gzcompress($content, 9, ZLIB_ENCODING_GZIP),
    'ACL' => 'public-read',
    'ContentType' => 'text/javascript',
    'ContentEncoding' => 'gzip'
));
```

The relevant part being `gzcompress($content, 9, ZLIB_ENCODING_GZIP)`, as AWS S3 wouldn't recognize the file nor serve it in the right format without the last `ZLIB_ENCODING_GZIP` parameter.